# Seasonal allergies home remedies

Tags: allergy, allergen, pollen, seasonal-allergies

Like many I have seasonal allergies and spring time is hell

I am allergic to grass and tree pollen

- Are there any home remedies that actually work ?
- Any way to train body to adapt?

Comment: Are you only talking about home remedies (as per your title), or also medication (since the body of your question doesn't specify)?

Comment: Only home remedies

Answer (score 3):

- Nettle-Peppermint Tea: Based on the mechanism of action, it should be noted that plain peppermint or used other ways should help.

[everyday-roots.com](http://everydayroots.com/allergy-remedies)

> peppermint contains a type of flavonoid called luteolin-7-O-rutinoside
>   which can help inhibit the activity and secretion of anti-inflammatory
>   enzymes, such as histamines, and greatly reduce the dreadful
>   discomfort that comes along them.

- Bee Pollen. This is said to work if local honey doesn't. Basically you take the allergens before the season to help build a immunity. The honey must be clean and free from insecticides.

This study from 2013 showed a improving in allergy symptoms after honey in high doses over 8 weeks: [Ingestion of honey improves the symptoms of allergic rhinitis: evidence from a randomized placebo-controlled trial in the East coast of Peninsular Malaysia.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24188941)

[everyday-roots.com](http://everydayroots.com/allergy-remedies)

> make sure you are not anaphylactic or severely allergic to bees, or so
>   allergic to pollen that you experience anaphylaxis.

2011 study about Birch Pollen Honey between November and March helped reduce 60% of allergy symptoms.

- Citrus is suppose to help due to the fact that it nourished your immune system. But due to this [ncbi article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1578094), it does not appear to be that effective.
- [Lavender oil inhalation](http://Lavender%20essential%20oil%20inhalation%20suppresses%20allergic%20airway%20inflammation%20and%20mucous%20cell%20hyperplasia%20in%20a%20murine%20model%20of%20asthma.):

> Lvn inhibits allergic inflammation and mucous cell hyperplasia with
>   suppression of T-helper-2 cell cytokines and Muc5b expression in a
>   murine model of asthma. Consequently, Lvn may be useful as an
>   alternative medicine for bronchial asthma.

[healthyfocus.org](https://healthyfocus.org/essential-oils-for-allergies/) also lists some other oils that may help, such as eucalyptus, lemon and peppermint.

- Onions are supposed to contain [Quercetin](http://www.webmd.com/vitamins-supplements/ingredientmono-294-quercetin.aspx?activeingredientid=294&activeingredientname=quercetin)  which is supposed to work similarly to anti-histamines to inhibit inflammation and secondarily bronchodilate.

[healthline.com](http://www.healthline.com/health/allergies/best-natural-antihistamines) supports research for onions helping relieve some allergy symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Local honey.

There's no science to support it as far as I can find, but there are many people who swear by it. (I know several personally.) Considering that's its harmless, cheap and tasty, it's probably worth a try.

Comment: Two answers, neither provides citations, but only the one that specifically states there's no science to cite is downvoted with no explanation. Go figure.

Comment: I think you'll find I was downvoted as well, but I'm not in the mood for writing an essay on this. I mostly use the Natural Medicines database through a school subscription so I can't just link the hayfever page from that.

Comment: One small study showed no difference between local honey, national honey, and corn syrup. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11868925 It's possible that either of these three coating the throat would provide relief from some symptoms. Honey has shown effect in wound healing however http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bjs.1800750718/abstract

Comment: @BenCannon Yeah, I'm familiar with that article, but I view it with a grain of salt. It was a *very* small sample and there don't seem to be any better ones. Failure to find an effect in one small study offers very little confidence, especially in the face of a mountain of anecdotal evidence to the contrary.

Comment: True, but try telling that to the skeptics.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your post, however maybe you should consider adding citations. Your post thus far could benefit from this as it is not supported by any sources and does not fit the usual format.  For assistance see the Help center, scope or respond here. Good luck :)

Comment: @Pobrecita I'm familiar with the site, thanks. Did you not read what I wrote? If I had citations, I certainly would post them. In any case, I've made no assertions of fact that require citations.

Comment: I thought that personal references did not count on this site as relevant citations. I may be mistaken I have not been on this site very long.  However, even if there is no science behind it linking some of the opinions might prove useful for people wanting to look deeper.

Comment: @Pobrecita On that you're right. I'll try to find time tomorrow to add some content to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Anything high in sulfur compounds (brassicas and alliums, particularly garlic, mustard, and horseradish) or high in vitamin C can help boost the immune system, although I can't tell you off-hand about the technicalities of why they help in the case of an over-active immune system when it comes to allergies, but from personal experience in improving my own hayfever symptoms it works.

As for adaptation, there has been a lot of recent experimental interest in the role that particular intestinal flora can play in allergies (among other things). So a diverse, balanced, diet high in unprocessed fibre could help.

And sometimes avoidance can be a good remedy. You can usually find pollen forecasts (dry windy days are the bad days). So maybe don't plan a picnic on those days, or mowing the lawns using a dust-mask and goggles (although the payoff there is that you overheat much more quickly!)